# call an event from another event in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question when programing in c#. I want to call an event from another event like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 formulario = new Form2();
        formulario.ShowDialog();
// here i call an event from the second form. that event is radiobutton_checkedchange

formulario.radioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
```

The problem is that i look everyware how to solve this problem... They said me that an event is like a method but i think is not the same, because when i call that event like a method it looks like i call it just once. The event dont recognize the checked change.

am I wrong ? is this posible in c#. Thanks to all, i'm new in programing with events. And sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is this question targeting a WebForms application?

Comment: You are not calling event. You are calling method that handle event. Can you please show Form2 class with your specific event ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Trying to trick the UI into thinking an event has taken place when it really hasn't doesn't seem like a good idea.  Can't you just, well, change the check box directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` is not an event, it is probably an event handler. In the end, it is still a method like all others.

You shouldn't directly call the event handler of an event, just create another method and what the call there. Put this in your `Form2`:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // private, only accessible from the class itself
    this.SetState();
}

public void SetState()
{ // public, accessible from anywhere

    // put your original code from radioButton1_CheckedChanged here
}
```

In that way, you don't have to call event specific code, but you can write that away in a separate method, which is easier to use and clearer in its purpose.

**If both forms share the same data object / view model, you can set the value from there. That would be better from a OOP perspective.** Look into MVVM or MVC for good design patterns to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have logic in `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` that you *also* want to call when the button is clicked. If that's the case, then move the common logic to a new method and call it from both places.

If you want to change the checked status of `radioButton1` then just change its status. Event hnadlers *respond* to UI changes, they do not *generate* them.